# How to apply CSS to iframe using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How do I access the iframe and override the elements style "td.rank" ? 
This is what I've got so far:

```
<script>

var head = $("#iframe11").contents().find("head");
var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
          'td.rank{background-color: #fc6b0a!important;}; ' +
          '</style>';
$(head).append(css);


</script>

<iframe src="http://www.example.com" id="iframe11" style="margin-left: 174px; width: 401px; border: 0px solid black; height: 358px; opacity: 0.85; margin-top: 23px;"></iframe>
```

When I open the code using "inspect element" - I don't even see the CSS code part in the `<head>` tag of the iframe.

Comment: try this...`$("iframe").contents().find("td.rank").css("background-color", "#fc6b0a!important");`

Comment: iframe document should also have to be on same domain and port.

Comment: and if it's 2 different websites? @Jai

Comment: Then quentin has answered it. "security policy". You can't touch things hosted on other domains while it is available in the iframe for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You if would like add css style inside iframe using jQuery then just follow below steps...

**1. First create 'index.html' file and add below code in it**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#iframe').load(function() {
                $("#iframe").contents().find("head").append("<style>.text_color{color:red;}@page{margin:0;}</style>");  
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2. Next create another file called 'iframe.html' and add below code to it**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="text"><span class="text_color">Content inside iframe goes here<span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**3. Next run 'index.html' file and now see 'Content inside iframe goes here' text color will changed to red color**

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the frame document is on the same origin as the framing document so you don't have a [security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access) violation.
2. Move the script so it appears after the frame so that the element exists before you try to access it
3. Move the code into a function and use that as a `load` handler for the frame so that the DOM you want to manipulate exists before you try to manipulate it